# What is the meaning of characters in the comment?

Tags: c++, qt

I often read C++ code in woboq with code browser.

But I can't understand some characters in comments.

There are many characters like `\c` , `\sa`, `\fn`.

I think these are abbreviations of some terms.

For example,

```
>A QObject instance is said to have a \e{thread affinity}, or that
it \e{lives} in a certain thread. When a QObject receives a
\l{Qt::QueuedConnection}{queued signal} or a \l{The Event
System#Sending Events}{posted event}, the slot or event handler
will run in the thread that the object lives in.
```

\e and \l are used in this comment.

others:

```
>\sa QMetaObject, QPointer, QObjectCleanupHandler, Q_DISABLE_COPY()
\sa {Object Trees & Ownership}
```

What does \sa mean correctly?

```
>If \a block is true, signals emitted by this object are blocked
(i.e., emitting a signal will not invoke anything connected to it).
If \a block is false, no such blocking will occur.
```

There are many \alphabets in comments.

Where can I know what these characters mean?

I think \c means class. \fn means function.
I'm very confused with these abbreviations.

Do you know something?

Comment: My guess would be, the source code is processed by some tool that reads those comments and turns them into documentation. Those special sequences guide the formatting of that documentation in some way. [Doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/) is a popular tool for this; but these comments don't seem to be in Doxygen format, so some other tool is probably used.

Comment: Purely guessing, `\e` probably means "emphasis" (e.g. format in italic font). `\l` is "link"; the two parameters in braces that follow are the section of the documentation to link to, and the link text. `\sa` is likely "see also".

Comment: Ah, here it is: [QDoc tool](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/01-qdoc-manual.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do you know something?

These are [QDoc commands](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/13-qdoc-commands-topics.html). For example:

> [\l (link)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/08-qdoc-commands-creatinglinks.html#l-link)
>
> The `\l` **link command is used to create a hyperlink to many different kinds of targets.** The command's general syntax is:
>
> ```
> \l [ link criteria ] { link target } { link text }
> ```
>
> [\fn (function)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/13-qdoc-commands-topics.html#fn-function)
>
> The `\fn` **command is for documenting a function**. The argument is the function's signature, including its template parameters (if any), return type, const-ness, and list of formal arguments with types. If the named function doesn't exist, QDoc emits a warning.
>
> [\c (code font)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/04-qdoc-commands-textmarkup.html#c-code-font):
>
> The `\c` **command is used for rendering variable names, user-defined class names, and C++ keywords (for example, int and for) in the code font**. The command renders its argument using a monospace font.

(emphasis mine)

This is a format that the [QDoc tool](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/01-qdoc-manual.html) uses for formatting and extraction of comments to/from source files.

Comment: Thank you very much. May I ask one more thing? I found \c ns in comments. What does ns mean ? NameSpace? This has no backslash but I think it is also an abbreviation.

Comment: \macro QT_NAMESPACE
    \internal
    If this macro is defined to \c ns all Qt classes are put in a namespace
    called \c  ns. Also, moc will output code putting metaobjects etc.
    into namespace \c ns.

Comment: @Ninjya See my updated answer where i've added meaning of `\c` command.

Comment: That is to say, ns is variable names, user-defined class names, and C++ keywords in the code font. Hmm. but I couldn't know what ns is. I don't know if I can reach the term or not, I'll try it.